# Passing Chinese characters to argparse in Python3.8

Tags: python, argparse, python-3.8

I have an argument parser that looks like this:

```
class Parser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def optparse():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        mandatory = parser.add_argument_group("mandatory")
        mandatory.add_argument(
            "-k", "--keyword", dest="keywordToUse", default=None, help="Specify a keyword"
        )
        mandatory.add_argument(
            "-f", "--keyword-file", dest="keywordFile", default=None,
            help="Specify a list of keywords (one per line) to run through"
        )

        return parser.parse_args()
```

What I want to do is pass Chinese characters to the `-k` argument like this: `python roulette.py -k 测试`. What I've tried is to define a unicode function to encode the string using the following code:

```
def to_unicode(s, encoder):
    
    def unicode(s, *_):
        return codecs.encode(s, *_)
    
    return unicode(s, encoder)
```

I've also tried using the system file encoding to encode the string as well using this function:

```
def uni_arg(b_string):
    unicode_string = b_string.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    return unicode_string
```

These encode the string, but during the output of the characters I get the following:

```
[10:12:28][I] starting search on a total of 1 unique keyword(s)
[10:12:28][D] currently processing keyword: b'\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95'
[10:12:28][D] attempting search with keyword: b'\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95'
[10:12:29][I] found a total of 0 result(s) using keyword: b'\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95'
```

What I'm expecting to see is the Chinese characters in the output, like this:

```
[10:12:28][I] starting search on a total of 1 unique keyword(s)
[10:12:28][D] currently processing keyword: '测试'
[10:12:28][D] attempting search with keyword: '测试'
[10:12:29][I] found a total of 0 result(s) using keyword: '测试'
```

How can I do this successfully using argparse?

Comment: Just... don't do anything, I think? You have unicode strings by default in python. By doing "encode" you're converting them to bytes object (hence the `b` before the opening quote`) which is completely opposite of unicode.

Comment: Not doing anything produces `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 48-49: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Huh, weird... Anyway, the quickest would be just to use whatever got you this `b'\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95'` result and add `.decode()` at the end to convert it back to unicode

Comment: Also, this error you posted seems to be something else. You don't have positions "48-49" in your example. Is it for file parsing? Or some saving at the end, maybe?

Comment: I'm trying the decode thing right now, yeah I'm not sure what the error means, there's more to the program, but none of it is reading from a file, it is adding it to a list though so maybe that?

Comment: So with the `.decode()`, i used the `to_unicode` function and added `codecs.decode(unicode_str)`. Now I get the error: `roulette.py: error: argument -k/--keyword: invalid to_unicode value: '测试'`

Comment: Where are you using this `optparse` method? or the `to_unicode`?  You show a class and function, but not code that actually uses them  Do a print(args)` of the Namespaced produced by `optparse`.  It that looks fine then this is not an `argparse` issue.  A full **traceback** of the error(s) will help.

Comment: I think I figured it out. By decoding the characters in the passed string to `cp850` and replacing them with `xmlcharrefreplace` I'm able to output the xml replacements. From there I can easily just do `html.unescape` and output the info @hpaulj